# WooCommerce - Triggering variation select with custom select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to use FancySelect.js to style the select boxes used on WooCommerce and have managed a few but I'm struggling with the Variation form on product pages.

While FancySelect triggers a change event on the original select box, it appears to affect nothing. Looking at the javascript used in the variations form, it looks like they've unbinded the change event on the select box and are handling it some other way, by triggering events on the `.variations_form` instead. I can't seem to get it to work though.

My code is something along the lines of:

```
        $('.summary select').fancySelect().on('change.fs', function() {
            $(this).trigger('change.$');
            $('.variations_form').trigger('woocommerce_variation_select_change');
        });
```

I've tried triggering multiple events but none seem to have any affect.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: try this... inspect element the fancyselect on your browser. look for the select element... adjust the css using dev tools when you inspect it. make it visible.. then try changing the value of the fancyselect.. see if the original select changes value...

Comment: Yeah it does change the select value, but it doesn't trigger the variations to change. However if I then manually change the actual select field, it does. So I think changing the select (maybe on click) is triggering something else, like the `.variations_form`.

Comment: try to trigger the click...

Comment: Yep, just tried that too :) however, while tinkering I think I figured it out. Will post as answer for future devs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the original trigger didn't work, for reasons I can't quite work out. However, manually triggering  a change event on the original select box worked to some degree, but it wouldn't update fancySelect's "Trigger" element. I think this was because the original select's options didn't get a `:selected` attribute (for whatever reason). I've had to add a custom event to fancySelect to manually trigger it's `updateText()` method.

Updated code:

```
$('.summary .options li').on('click', function(){
    $('.summary select').trigger('change').trigger('select.fs');
});
```

And the additional event for fancySelect (which I'll try contribute to if I get chance):

```
sel.on('select.fs', function(){
    updateTriggerText();
});
```

Cheers.